# How to get full month date which are not added in database table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello i have a sql query which return following data as shown on below image.
My Sql query is

```
SELECT datei, sum(amount)
FROM
(
 SELECT datei, amount, 1 AS identification FROM income
 UNION ALL
 SELECT datee, amount, 2 AS identification FROM expense
 UNION ALL
 SELECT date, amount, 3 AS identification FROM others
) t
GROUP BY datei
ORDER BY datei ASC
```

And Result is

[image: Click Here For Image]

this return me a date when customer is registered.
I need all date of full month. which are skipped in database.
As Example in image After 2017/09/04 next date is 2017/09/06 So 05 Date is Skipped.

I need all Days In between 01 to 12 Days as according to example shown in image.
how can i get that USING PHP ?

Comment: Post your PHP or query so we can help.

Comment: I posted query. please Check

Comment: Is all your data sets equal in number of data fields.

Comment: No its not equal.

Comment: according to the SQL site `Each SELECT statement within the UNION ALL must have the same number of fields in the result sets with similar data types.` this might be the problem.

Comment: But i dont need that in query.
Using PHP Also You can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to outer join table or select that have all days in the month.
[Friddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d60cb9/8)

```
select date(concat('2017-09-',  d)) AS dt
from (
    select 1 AS d
    union select 2
    union select 3
    union select 4
    union select 5
    union select 6
    union select 7
    union select 8
    union select 9
    union select 10
    union select 11
    union select 12
    union select 13
    union select 14
    union select 15
    union select 16
    union select 17
    union select 18
    union select 19
    union select 20
    union select 21
    union select 22
    union select 23
    union select 24
    union select 25
    union select 26
    union select 27
    union select 28
    union select 29
    union select 30
    union select 31
) as t
having dt is not null
```

Comment: Thanx @Vasil Nikolov

Comment: @TarangPanchal Remember this is fixed month and year here. With fixed date 31st.

Comment: Date is not fixed, you can try with '2017-02-' and you will see 28 days. The key is "having dt is not null"

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work, haven't tested though

```
select date, sum(amount) as sumOfAmount
from
(
  SELECT DATE_ADD('2008-01-01', INTERVAL @rn:=@rn+1 DAY) as date from (select @rn:=-1)t, `your_table_name` limit 365
) d left outer join `your_table_name` using (date)
group by date
```